# Scroll through the listview and get all selected items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I get the data that is displayed in a listview, I need to print them on a voucher.

The data in the listview comes from select database.

To check if the item is marked to be printed I'm doing it this way:

```
 var sparseArray = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.List).CheckedItemPositions;
for (var i = 0; i < sparseArray.Size(); i++ )
{
   Console.Write(sparseArray.KeyAt(i) + "=" + sparseArray.ValueAt(i) + ",");
}
```

In this case I have the position and if it is marked. Now I need to get the contents.

Comment: Looks like you are getting it here sparseArray.ValueAt(i) What is the problem?

Comment: I need to get what is written in each line of the listview

Comment: Do you have an adapter for your ListView?

Comment: Yes, I have. Yes.

Comment: Then use index and get the value from your adapter

Comment: I do not understand. There's another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my listview:

```
 getdate();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, players);
        lv.Adapter = adapter;
        lv.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
```

Comment: You shouldn't provide this as an answer, it should go to edit your question. I updated my answer. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You have an adapter which has list of your objects (lets call them `List<Player> players`).

Implement function

```
List<Player> GetSelectedPlayers(int[] indexes)
{
   //build query to get list of objects from players using provided indexes
}
```

and call it in activity

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: show the code of your adapter and how you populate your list

Comment: Ok I just finished

Answer (score 0):

If you have the positions, then you can get the item at the position using the listviews adapter using:

```
adapter.getItem(position);
```